# LARAVEL Get file Content and split to save in another table

Tags: laravel

Hi everyone I need your help on how to split value from textarea and insert in a users table using laravel, I was able to get file content = "name | username | password", I need to split each value so I ca save it to a users table the file itself is save in a different table, should I put it in a different method or just specify my target table in the same as the file will be saved? Your help will be much appreciated.

UploadController:

```
    public function store(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            ['filename' => 'required|mimes:txt,jpeg,png,jpg,bmp|max:2048']
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }
        // if validation success
        if ($file   =   $request->file('filename')) {
            $filename = 'uploaded-here.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //stored in laravel local storage
            $target_path    =   $file->storeAs('uploaded-here/', $filename);
            if ($file->move($target_path, $filename)) {
                // save file name in the database
                $file   =   File::create(['filename' => $filename]);
                return back()->with("success", "File uploaded successfully");
            }
        }
    }
```

html code:

```
    <div class="form-group" {{ $errors->has('filename') ? 'has-error' : '' }}>
          <label for="filename"></label>
               <input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" class="form-control">
               <span class="text-danger"> {{ $errors->first('filename') }}</span>
               <textarea id="editor" name="editor></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md"> Upload </button>
```

js

```
      window.onload = function() {
        var doc = document.getElementById('filename');
        if (doc) {
            doc.addEventListener('change', getFile);
        }
      }
      function getFile(event) {
        const input = event.target
        if ('files' in input && input.files.length > 0) {
             placeFileContent(
                 document.getElementById('editor'),
                 input.files[0])
        }
     }
     function placeFileContent(target, file) {
        readFileContent(file).then(content => {
            target.value = content
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
     }
     function readFileContent(file) {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result)
            reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
            reader.readAsText(file)
         })
     }
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the text file to parse.

Comment: Hi @ChristopheHubert the text file content is pretty much it = name | username | password, example errol | errol.boneo13@gmail.com | password123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error. Quotation closed sign is missing in `name` attribute of `textarea`.

```
<textarea id="editor" name="editor"></textarea>
```

You can split using JavaScipt's `split()` method. Like follwoing:

Say, you have the textarea value as your given format: `name | email | password`
as you have given example: `example errol | errol.boneo13@gmail.com | password123`.

Let's say, you have get the textarea value,

```
var textValue = document.getElementById('editor').value;
textValue = textValue .split(" | ");
var name = textValue [0];
var email = textValue [1];
var password = textValue [2];
```

Hope it helps....

**EDIT::**

As you wanted to do in laravel, you can do like following:

```
$textValue = $request->editor;
$textValue = explode(" | ", $textValue );
$name = $textValue [0];
$email = $textValue [1];
$password = $textValue [2];
```

Comment: Thanks it does work however I'm not gonna be doing this in javascript to save time instead I want to do it in laravel directly before save, I am new to laravel that's why any help will be very helpful.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check... @ErrolBoneo

Comment: Thank  you so much @Nazem Mahmud, you are a life saver I cant find the right words to express how I deeply appreciates your help, this code works perfectly hope to see a lot of your work

Comment: well, you can upvote and accept my answer if it works :D @ErrolBoneo

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have an exceeding 15 reputation for my vote to be publicly seen which is why you cant see it hahaha I would upvote it a thousand times if I could, also I have one question, how to call 2 methods in 1 controller? apparently these data from file needs to be inserted in users and the file is in files table, last one

Comment: if its in the same class, you can use `$this` to call one method from inside another method, like, `$this::anotherMethod($param1,..)`. if it is from another class, you can use directly class name for static method, like `ClassName::methodName()` or you may use dependency injection. if you don't understand dependency injection, please study it.

Comment: Great thanks it works thanks for your help, by the way what's your social media accounts I would love to follow you.